# The difference between a basis of vectors vs functions

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If my understanding is correct, I can see that for any set of linearly independent vectors $V = v_1, v_2, ..., v_n$ these establish a basis for $R^n$ by way of a set of coordinates $X = x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ multiplied into this vector set.

However, how does this conceptually translate to a set of functions?

For instance, with vectors, the classic cartesian 2-space is the set $V = (E_x,E_y)$ multiplied by $X = (x,y)$:

$$x*E_x + y*Ey = R^2$$

...but for another 2-space we might have the set $S = (sin(t), cos(t))$ as the basis, and then have the following as the vector space:

$$x*sin(t) + y*cos(t)$$

What I am not understanding here is how to conceptualize this 2-space of functions. For the vectors, my understanding is:

$$E_x = \left[ \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \end{array} \right], E_y = \left[ \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 1 \end{array} \right]$$

Therefore:

$$x \left[ \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \end{array} \right]+ y \left[ \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 1 \end{array} \right] = \begin{array}{cc}x\\y \end{array}$$

This gives us the x and y coordinates of the resulting vector, which constitutes $R²$.

However, for the set of equations $S$ as a basis, the only thing I can think of is to see $S = (t,sin(t)),(t,cos(t))$, and then compute it in a similar way to get:

$$x \left[ \begin{array}{c} t \\ sin(t) \end{array} \right]+ y \left[ \begin{array}{c} t \\ cos(t) \end{array} \right] = \begin{array}{cc}t(x+y)\\x*sin(t)+y*cos(t) \end{array}$$

Is this correct? It seems to be valid, but may be over-complicating things.

*(pardon the poor LaTeX)*

Comment: The space of functions spanned by $\sin(t)$ and $\cos(t)$ is simply the set of all functions of the form $x\sin(t)+y\sin(t)$. You don't need the extra $t$ component. Perhaps you're thinking that any two-dimensional vector space must be written with two components in an array, but that's not true. For example, the $xy$-plane is a two-dimensional subspace of 3D space, and any point on it is of the form $x\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix} + y\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\0\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Oh I see...so in a sense the combinations of the functions is a subspace of $R^2$ that inherently is $t,f(t)$ for all $x$ and $y$? From this, the extra $t$ component is unneeded just as the extra dimension in your 3-space example is unneeded to describe the $R^2$ subspace?

Comment: Your space of functions is *not* a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$, because none of the functions in it are elements of $\mathbb R^2$. The $xy$-plane is not a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$ either -- maybe that was a poorly chosen example, consider the subspace $x\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\0\end{bmatrix} + y\begin{bmatrix}3\\-1\\-2\end{bmatrix}$ instead. The point is that you should stop thinking of two-dimensional vector spaces as being inherently tied to $\mathbb R^2$.